# how can i compress video files in webrtc ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming, webrtc

I am working with Webrtc Video streaming.

```
- (RTCMediaConstraints *)defaultMediaStreamConstraints {
NSArray *mandatoryConstraints = @[
                                  [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxWidth" value:@"640"],
                                  [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxHeight" value:@"480"],
                                  [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxFrameRate" value:@"15"],
                                   ];

NSArray *optionalConstraints = @[];
RTCMediaConstraints* constraints1 =
[[RTCMediaConstraints alloc]
 initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints
 optionalConstraints:nil];
return constraints1;
}
- (RTCMediaConstraints *)defaultPeerConnectionConstraints {
     NSArray *mandatoryConstraints = @[ [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxHeight" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"640"]],
                                   [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxWidth" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"480"]],
                                   [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxFrameRate" value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"15"]]
                                   ];
     NSArray *optionalConstraints = @[];

     RTCMediaConstraints* constraints1 =
                  [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc]
                  initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints
                  optionalConstraints:optionalConstraints];
return constraints1;
}
```

but,it's not working.it's set high video quality streaming.
how to compress quality?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the video bandwidth directly inside the SDP before setting it as the local session description and sending it to the peer.

Find `a=mid:video\r\n` and append `b=AS:128\r\n` to it.

You can do the same for the audio stream by looking for `a=mid:audio\r\n`.

For instance, given the following SDP:

```
v=0 
o=- 487255629242026503 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1 
s=- 
t=0 0 

a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0 
a=ice-ufrag:8a1/LJqQMzBmYtes 
a=ice-pwd:sbfskHYHACygyHW1wVi8GZM+ 
a=ice-options:google-ice 
a=fingerprint:sha-256 28:4C:19:10:97:56:FB:22:57:9E:5A:88:28:F3:04:
   DF:37:D0:7D:55:C3:D1:59:B0:B2:81 :FB:9D:DF:CB:15:A8 
a=setup:actpass 
a=mid:audio 
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level 
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
```

You would have to append `b=AS:128` between `a=mid:audio` and `a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level`.